# Don't make refreshing a Review page behave like a Skip

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, mobile-web

I often contribute to Stack Exchange via my mobile phone (on Chrome browser).

I was reviewing the only entry in the First Question Review Queue on the mobile-version on my phone, then wanted to see the post using the desktop-version on my phone to see it rendered more realistically.

When I ticked the Desktop-site button in my Chrome browser, the page reloaded -- as expected.  The trouble is that the reloaded page said that the Review Queue was cleared and I could no longer review the post that I had every intention of reviewing.

Can something be done to only exclude posts from my queue where I explicitly Skipped it?

Comment: ...wait a sec... a short while later, I refreshed the master list of all Review Queues and the excluded entry was available again and I could re-access it. I suppose the problem was specifical to the First Question Review Queue page.  I just repeated the issue again.  It is currently not in the master list.  I'll give it some time and refresh.  Okay, less than a minute later, I refreshed and it was back in my master list.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant but in the First Answer queue it can take somewhere between 1 and 15 minutes for the queue to refresh. Say for example you've done 20 reviews in a day and are waiting for the queue to go over 150 items so you can review more (past the 20/day cap), there's some delay between 151º item entering the queue and you being allowed to continue reviewing. What seems noteworthy in your case is that apparently the post gets temporarily marked as "skipped" if you're accessing from a different device (but in any case I think the 1-15 minute delay in polling the queue happened.)

Comment: Regarding [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375412/dont-make-refreshing-a-review-page-behave-like-a-skip#comment1250426_375412), yes some queues kick you out for a minute or 10 if you navigate away to research for a better review decision and others let you back in right away - I always use a different browser to avoid that, but when you are switching modes that isn't going to help avoid this darn annoying problem.